# All my microservices have their own db's, should I create common microservice to handle connections?

Tags: database, architecture, microservices

I have a number of microservices that maintain their own databases (mongodb, elastic, mysql) and each of the microservices I have to set-up a new connection constantly.

I was considering would it be wise if I created another microservice, that could handle these connections for the microservices, before they start up.

Example:
My API Gateway microservice gets a request for search, it then calls search microservice, which before the search starts, calls the database setup miscroservice and returns an established connection back to it, based on what microservice called it (in this case - the search microservice).

Would it be better, if I just found out what connection is needed inside the API Gateway? Or should I just leave the logic separately in each microservice.

Comment: How would you pass an "established connection" around?

Comment: Hey @HenkHolterman ,
I was thinking that the db microservice could test to see if the connection is open and then pass the needed parameters (db type, db name, login etc.) in standard json/xml body back to the microservice that needs the connection. I guess problem is that I am exposing the db of one microservice to another. Would you consider if this has any pros at all? Or it's just all cons :) ?

Comment: Looks to me like you are adding yet another dependency. And it could quickly become a bottleneck.

Comment: If you do use this, call it a ConfigurationService because that's what it is. And if that's a good idea depends very much on your environment, how you plan to manage things after deployment etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would break the microservices encapsulation by assuming the type of persistence that each microservice is using.

Each microservice should be **free to use whatever persistence type it wants** or to **change it when it wants** transparently, without notifying or requesting permission from the other microservices about this.

Comment: Yes! So many people get this part of microservices wrong, you should never be integrating across the database.